# Xamarin.Auth doesn't persist data after closing the app - ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I have built an application through Xamarin.Forms, I am using xamarin.auth to save sensitive (login) data on each platform, Android app works correctly, I login to the app, save the data, close the app, re-open it and no need to login, the app goes directly to the home page, but in ios every time I open the app I need to login, and after that I close it and re-open it again I need to login again, I think there is something missed, I am debugging on a real iPhone 7 plus device, any help please?

Comment: you need to be more specific about persisting the data, what are you using?  SQLite ? Realm? or just the settings plugin ?

Comment: Iam using xamarin.auth sdk - you can have a fast look here https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/general/store-credentials/ - to save the data, I created a dependency service in each platform to handle this, in android it works perfectly, but ios the app lose the data when close it